# Override org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource for jdbc data direct sqlserver driver

Tags: java, solr, datadirect

I need to override the JdbcDataSource class getConnection() method to unlock **Data direct** driver.

When solr is executing the sql queries present in solr-data-config.xml inside solr cores, it is unable to execute the sql queries.
It is failing with error "**this driver is locked for use with embedded applications**".

I could override the getConnection() method & unlock the driver by extending the JdbcDataSource class.
But solr is not picking up my extended class. How to configure solr with extended JdbcDataSource.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create a new class that extends the old one, override `getConnection()` call, include the class in a .jar-file, add the .jar-file to the libraries being loaded by Solr, then use the new name in your data source definition - `dataSource type="NewAndImprovedJdbcDataSource"`. If it doesn't allow overriding getConnection, you might have to copy the content to a new file and create a "new", separate datasource instead.

Comment: I overriden the getConnection method. Where can i add the feild dataSource type = "NewAndImprovedJdbcDataSource"?
And where can i place the jar in solr installation directory? I am not sure in which location I can add my jar file.

Comment: You add the .jar file to the `lib` elements in `solrconfig.xml`: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html - You reference the datasource in the data-config.xml file: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#fieldreaderdatasource

Comment: Thanks for sharing the configuration steps. I followed the steps. But, after I wrote a custom data source which extends JdbcDataSource, after running the solr, i am facing this error.



 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/JdbcDataSource

Comment: You still have to load the libraries for the JdbcDataSource if you're extending it. The Solr log will show you all the jars being loaded.

Comment: SolrDataImportHandler is loaded as part of solr-config.xml.
 <lib dir="{solr-installation-directory}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
Am I going in the right way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211384/discussion-between-adiraju-uttej-and-matslindh).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create a new class that extends the old one, override `getConnection()` call, include the class in a .jar-file, add the .jar-file to the libraries being loaded by Solr, then use the new name in your data source definition - `dataSource type="NewAndImprovedJdbcDataSource"`.

You must the .jar file to the [lib elements in `solrconfig.xml`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html):

```
<lib dir="../../../<path>/" regex="my-library\.jar" />
```

You then reference the datasource in the data-config.xml file:

```
<dataSource name="<name>" type="YourCustomClass" />
```